# How to parse and format International Dates to required standard in java?

Tags: java, localization, internationalization, format, simpledateformat

In our project,we are trying to parse and format different international dates in particular standard format but it is resulting into Unparsable Date Exception, here is my sample code :

```
import java.text.DateFormatSymbols;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.TimeZone;

public class InternationalizationDate {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {

        SimpleDateFormat dateFormatForDate = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd,yyyy");// Expected format

        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        String stringDate = "00:00:00 08/09/2015";// This date can be in any format as per the systems local regional settings.

        SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat();

        System.out.println("Local Date Format Pattern : " + simpleDateFormat.toLocalizedPattern());

        // DateFormatSymbols dateFormatSymbols = simpleDateFormat.getDateFormatSymbols();
        // String[] eras = { "BC" };
        // dateFormatSymbols.setEras(eras);
        // simpleDateFormat.setDateFormatSymbols(dateFormatSymbols);

        Date date = simpleDateFormat.parse(stringDate);
        String formattedDate = dateFormatForDate.format(date);
        System.out.println("Converted Format : " + formattedDate);

    }
}
```

Where we are going wrong ?

Comment: Well in the code you've given, the value ("00:00:00 08/09/2015") clearly doesn't match the format you're specifying ("MMM dd,yyyy"). Why are you calling `applyPattern` to force the simple date formatter to use that specific pattern, when I thought the whole point of it was to use the local pattern according to the default locale. (Admittedly even then you need to know which pattern to use - whether it's a date or date/time pattern, for example.)

Comment: @JonSkeet Sorry , i will just update the code. But how can we deal with this then , i mean the date format can be anyone ?

Comment: Well we don't know where your data is coming from. You could potentially try multiple formats associated with the locale, or allow the user to specify the format.

Comment: @JonSkeet So we can not convert an international date in any format into a particular format ?

Comment: Not "in any format, without knowing what that format is" no. You can use `DateFormat.getDateInstance` etc to get several formats to try, but if the user is using something other than those, then no, there's just not enough information.

Comment: @JonSkeet Can you please take me through the implementation of DateFormat.getDateInstance w.r.t the above example ?

Comment: Well no, as I've never seen a format that looks like the value you're using - and I don't know what locale it's meant to be for. But look at the overloads of `getDateInstance` and `getDateTimeInstance` that take styles and locales - for any given locale, those methods can give you *lots* of options.

Comment: @JonSkeet Thanks, your hint DateFormat.getDateInstance lead us to the perfect solution.

Answer (score 0):

What cause the parse exception error is because the parse format doesn't match the date format, just change the this line of code:

```
 SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat();
```

To:

```
 SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss dd/MM/yyyy"); 
 // this match with "00:00:00 08/09/2015"
```